# sed regex issue

Tags: ubuntu, sed, regular-expression

I'm trying to replace a string in a file:

```
$RELEASE     = '1234';
```

The whitespace between RELEASE and the = symbol could be either spaces OR tabs. The quotes around the version number could be either single or double.

I currently am assuming spaces and single quotes at the moment just to try to get it working:

```
sed 's/$RELEASE[[:space:]]*\=[[:space:]]*'\''[0-9]*'\'';/$RELEASE = '\''1234'\'';/g' config.ini > config.ini
```

So after a lot of work, this works. But only if the string is spaces (as apposed to tabs) and single quotes as apposed to doubles. Here is what I have so far for trying to tackle the tabs...:

```
sed 's/$RELEASE([[:space:]]|\t)*\=([[:space:]]|\t)*'\''[0-9]*'\'';/$RELEASE = '\''1234'\'';/g' config.ini > config.ini
```

I've just read that /t isn't supported in most sed regular expressions... Is this true? Is there a [[:tab:]] type replacement? (I did try that)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just write a new one, e.g. `sed 's/^$RELEASE.*;$/$RELEASE = "foobar";/'`

Comment: drs, I'm trying to find the $RELEASE string in the file and replace it (this is in an ApacheAnt script)

Could be $RELEASE = '1222';
or $RELEASE       = "1221";

Comment: Thanks Ulrich. Good suggestion!

I've over complicated that for myself somewhat!!!

Comment: Do not redirect file to itself. In the end you may stay with an empty file. Use `sed -i` (only for gnu `sed`) instead or separate temporary file. Also you can use `\s` instead of `[[:space:]]` as it also includes \t and all other whitespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any problem with `[[:space:]]`. Here's a really silly little example showing the mixed-replacement of spaces and tabs:

```
$ echo -e 'A \t \t B' | sed 's/A[[:space:]]*B/WORKED/'
WORKED
```

You can also use `\s` which is often preferable with big `sed` strings because it's much shorter:

```
$ echo -e 'A \t \t B' | sed 's/A\s*B/WORKED/'
WORKED
```

---

Anyway, I think your actual problem is escaping those troublesome single quotes. I find the easiest way is to break out of the single quote string and have a double-quoted single quote and then (if needed) go back into the single quote line. Bash will automatically concatenate this all up for you.

```
$ echo 'This is a nice string and this is a single quote:'"'"' Nice?'
This is a nice string and this is a single quote:' Nice?
```

So all the space we saved with `\s` is about to get destroyed by this mega-quote situation:

```
$ echo -e '$RELEASE  \t = '"'"'1234'"'"';' |\
  sed 's/$RELEASE\s*=\s*'"'"'[0-9]*'"'"'\;/REPLACEMENT/'
```

Of course there is an argument that (because this looks like a PHP script) that you might be able to assume that if the line starts with `$RELEASE[\s=]+` you can just replace the whole line. Not always true obviously (the entire app could be one hideous line) but it makes your search and replace more palatable:

```
sed 's/$RELEASE[\s=]*.*/REPLACEMENT/'
```

---

And yes, general `sed` usage rules apply. Don't echo into a stream-editor (like `sed`) and redirect back into that file. *If* it works you could easily knacker the file.

Either use the `-i` argument (works for `sed`) or pipe into a application like sponge (which is like a delayed output):

```
sed -i '...' file
sed '...' file | sponge file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the expression and use `\1` to point to the group. E.g

```
sed 's/^\($RELEASE.*=\).*/\1 '"'1234'"'/' config.ini
```